# What is the difference between isset and empty?

Tags: php

What is the difference between `!isset` and `empty`, `isset` and `!empty` ??

Comment: http://virendrachandak.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/ first hit at google "php isset vs empty"

Comment: possible duplicate of [isset() or !empty() functions on all variables in your views? PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938061/isset-or-empty-functions-on-all-variables-in-your-views-php)

Comment: or [Why check both isset() and !empty()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Comment: The link in the first comment for "php isset vs empty" has been updated to http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Answer (score 17):

The type comparison tables should answer all questions about these operators: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: I didn't realize that `$x = "";` and `$x = null;` produced different results.  That's handy information to have.

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer would be that a variable can be set (not NULL) and yet be empty(can be assimilated to 0).
Consider an empty array for example.

From the link presented by @mjhennig, you can see that 0 is considered to be empty. So is False and the empty string(obviously) :)